# FXML: positioning multiple elements within an horizontal Box(HBox)

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, position, fxml

Within an Hbox, i do want to have a text as a title, as well as an search bar with a **submit** button.

The **title** should be positioned on the left but the **search** **bar** with the **submit** button on the right.

The way i did it:

```
<HBox>  
    <Label text="Penfactory Software"/> 
    <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
        <TextField fx:id="idSearch"  />
        <Button fx:id="idSubmit" text ="Submit" onAction="#submit"/> 
    </HBox>
</HBox>
```

Hbox can give its elements an position with alignment ="TOP_RIGHT".
The Issue: Only Top lvl HBox can give the alignment, otherly put, if there is a HBox within a HBox only the **top-level** HBox will **determine** where the elements are being placed.

How do i achieve the goal described above of having the title on the left and search + button on the right?

Comment: Do you want your title to aligned left and the others on the right? Do you have an image describing what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `Pane`. Set the `Pane's` max-width to `MAX_VALUE` and `Hgrow` to `ALWAYS`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label text="Hello world!">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <TextField />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Is this the only way to position elements?

Comment: You can also use Mig Layout.

Comment: I am not sure I know what Mig Layout is. Write an answer.

Comment: @Roman There are other options, but Sedrick's solution is probably the clearest and easiest to implement. One alternative is to embed a second `HBox`, like in your question, and then set it to always grow (e.g. `HBox.setHgrow(embeddedBox, Priority.ALWAYS)`), then set the correct alignments. Another alternative is to do what Sedrick did, but instead of a `Pane` you make the `Label` always grow (have to set its max width to the maximum). The most complicated alternative is to create your own layout.

Comment: I believe Mig Layout is Swing related. @M.S. Am I correct in that? If so, not sure how it applies to a [tag:javafx] question.

Comment: @Slaw It has a JavaFX implementation, check [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com). I did use in a project lately.

Comment: @Slaw On [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.miglayout/miglayout-javafx)